# Nginx how to forward 8080 to 80

Tags: nginx

Currently i have wordpress running on 192.168.2.1:8080

Nginx listening on port 80

I want to redirect all http request on port 8080 "http://192.168.2.1:8080" to port 80 "http://192.168.2.1"

My current nginx conf me does the opposite : "http://192.168.2.1" points me to "http://192.168.2.1:8080"

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 192.168.2.1;

location / {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.2.1:8080/;
}
```

How should i do this ?

PS : I've really tried all previous threads :/

Comment: What are you trying to solved? i belive here is an [X-AND-Y-Problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe have config like

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name 192.168.2.1;

location / {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.2.1:80/;
}
```

Listen is what you want for nginx to receive connections from, and as we can guess the proxy_pass is where you want them to go

Comment: If you write http:// without a double point which is, meaning, selecting a port — port 80 will be used by default - Both Works, but proxy_pass http://192.168.2.1:80/; the `:80` is not needed, due `proxy_pass http://192.168.2.1/;` will do the same. But Remind, about the Slash on the end, this could make a difference how requests will be handled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is not a proper answer, i can not have nginx listening on the same port as wordpress container is already occupying port 8080.